# How can I access specific data in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to delete the messages of every user before 30 days. When the user enters the application, their own messages are deleted. But I can't access every user's messages. I couldn't find what to write for the query.

This my message db:
[image]

This my Code to delete messages when the user opens an account :

```
   mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        ChatsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("message").child(currentUserID);
     

 long cutoff = new Date().getTime() - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(30, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        Query oldItems = ChatsRef.orderByChild("timestamp").endAt(cutoff);
        oldItems.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    itemSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });
```

How can I access the timestamp of each user?

Comment: I'm afraid that cannot be achieved using your actual database schema.

Comment: What kind of database schema do I need for this?

Comment: One that has no extra level between the actual data and the primary ID.

Comment: @AlexMamo can you show me an example of this

Comment: Are you allowed to change the database schema?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes i have this permission

Comment: One more question. You need a query to find all messages of the current user or of all users?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes..